# How to export settings from old installation of BDO

Tags: pc, black-desert-online

I've recently updated from w7 to w10 and reinstall Black Desert, and I was wandering which files I have to copy to keep my game settings(notifications, graphics, audio, and other game settings such as chat and hide or show pets and names)
basically everything.

Also i have the same computer but a different SSD with W10 instead of w7.

So two questions:

**Which files do i have to copy?**

**Do have to change anithing?(I'm concerned of paths like C://user/...)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on articles aimed at resetting your UI and settings (e.g. https://blackdesert.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/212549709-Clearing-your-gamecache), it seems like many of these settings are stored in the UserCache folder in Documents/Black Desert, as well as the Cache folder in your game installation folder. I do not know what files exactly are related to this, but it seems like copying over those 2 folders may help at least some.